# Why is ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor schedule method running task almost immediately?

Tags: java, concurrency, scheduled-tasks

We have some code in our product that uses the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor  schedule method to schedule tasks at intervals. The code is something like below --

```
public void schedule(Object o, Runnable task, long delay,
        TimeUnit unit) throws RejectedExecutionException {
    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor pool = ensurePoolExecutor(o.getClass());
    if (pool.isShutdown()) {
        log.warn("Cannot schedule task due to shutdown being called: {}",
                o.getClass().getSimpleName());
        return;
    }
    
    pool.schedule(task, delay, unit);
}
```

We are calling the above API with TimeUnit Milliseconds and delay around
158321 milliseconds (~ 2 mins). This code is working fine in our lab and in many other environments. However, we have seen in one of the customers environment, the delay argument passed to the schedule method is not respected and the task gets executed almost instantaneously. Any clues on why this is happening would be appreciated. Could it be because of some setting/misconfiguration in the particular VM? By the way, this code is run on Windows server machines.

Comment: What does `ensurePoolExecutor()` return?

Comment: It returns an instance of ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor